# Arduino with SoftwareSerial: 2 programs, same code, one not working

Tags: arduino

Have a simple program restarting an IoT device. Everything works fine, as expected. As soon as I put that code into my bigger program, it wont work anymore. The part where I read back from the device will just only return "" (empty strings). Anyone has a clue why?

The working program is just:

```
    #include <SoftwareSerial.h>

    SoftwareSerial NB_IOT_DEV (12, 13); //(RX = 0, TX = 1)
    String nbState = "";

    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println(F("Hello World"));

      NB_IOT_DEV.begin(9600);

      Serial.println(F("Sending EASY+Restart"));
      short i=0;
      NB_IOT_DEV.println("EASY+Restart");
      do {
        nbState = NB_IOT_DEV.readString();
        nbState.trim();
        Serial.print(F("NB State: "));
        Serial.println(nbState);
        delay (1000);
        i++;
      } while (nbState.indexOf("ModemStatus:Detached") == -1 && i < 50);


      Serial.println(F("Sending EASY+Device"));
      i=0;
      NB_IOT_DEV.println("EASY+Device");
      do {
        nbState = NB_IOT_DEV.readString();
        nbState.trim();
        Serial.print(F("NB State: "));
        Serial.println(nbState);
        delay (1000);
        i++;
      } while (nbState.indexOf("EASY#Device:Success") == -1 && i < 50);

    }

    void loop() {

    }
```

In the non-working sketch I have the code inside a function called from loop function, its exactly the same code, but .readString() just returns an empty string.

Comment: Please post the full non-working code.

Comment: String objects need more RAM than what the compiler tells. Is the RAM near its limit in your bigger sketch?

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason:
its impossible to have 2 devices connected via software serial same time
Workaround:
use .listen() function of SoftwareSerial to listen to the one you use in that moment